# Creating a legend for a scatter plot in D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, legend

I have written the following code snippets to create a legend for a scatter plot.

Basically, it is a simple example that uses Susie Lu's D3-legend module to create a legend for a scatter plot.

The webpage, however, shows nothing...

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

**my HTML code:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>D3 Legend</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.25.6/d3-legend.min.js"></script>

    <script src="data-script.js"></script>

    <svg id="scatterplot"></svg>
    <div id="legend"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**my CSS code:**

```
#legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**my JavaScript code:**

```
// Set up the scatter plot.
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);

var svg = d3.select("#scatterplot")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv").then(function (data, error) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x = +d.x;
        d.y = +d.y;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.x; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.y; })).nice();
    color.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.z; }));

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.z); });

    // Set up the legend.
    var legend = d3.legendColor()
        .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
        .title("Z Value")
        .scale(color);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .call(legend);
});
```

Comment: `d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {` should be `d3.csv("data.csv").then(function (data, error) {` because you use v7 ....

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post with the updated code. Is this correct now? It still shows nothing...

Answer (score 1):

It is your `legend` selector. In your CSS code, you are using **".legend"** as the selector, but in your JavaScript code, you are using **"#legend"** as the selector.

**--Updated--**

As your code, it seems that you are not calling the legend function properly. Instead of calling `d3.select("#legend").append("svg")`, you should call `svg.append("g")` to add the legend to the same SVG element as the scatter plot.

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);

var svg = d3.select("#scatterplot")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x = +d.x;
        d.y = +d.y;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.x; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.y; })).nice();
    color.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.z; }));

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.z); });

    // Set up the legend.
    var legend = d3.legendColor()
        .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
        .title("Z Value")
        .scale(color);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .call(legend);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed them all to `legend` but still the page shows nothing. Is that what you mean I should do? Or should I leave the `.legend` in my CSS code and only change the others to `legend`?

Comment: No, It is better to change the CSS selector into `#legend`.

Comment: Still to no avail... I have included the latest code in my updated question. Would you kindly see if you can spot what the problem is? Thank you

Comment: can repost the u[dated code ?

Comment: I have done that. I have updated my post with the updated code. Thanks

Comment: As your code, it seems that you are not calling the legend function properly. Instead of calling `d3.select("#legend").append("svg")`, you should call `svg.append("g")` to add the legend to the same SVG element as the scatter plot.

You can check my answer for the updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I copy-paste your js code into my script, still nothing shows...

Comment: As I guess,
It may be an issue with the data file or file paths to the data file and the CSS file.

Try checking the file paths of data file and the CSS file in HTML code. 

Also, make sure that the data file is in CSV format and that it is in the same directory as your HTML file.

If the file paths are correct and the data is in the correct format, then the issue may be with the D3-legend module itself. You can try using a different legend module or a different version of D3.js to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I just realized there is an error message when I open Developer Tools on my webpage: `Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/reem/data.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.`